# PHP mkdir permission denied on mounted hard drive

Tags: php, mount, mkdir, hard-drive

I'm trying to use the command mkdir in a php script to create a directory on a mounted hard-drive on a raspberry pi.
I have created the directory /mnt/hdd ( sudo mkdir /mnt/hdd ) and i'm mounting the device using the command :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/hdd
```

My php script is :

```
<?php
     mkdir("/mnt/hdd/storage_1/");
     mkdir("/mnt/hdd/storage_2/");
?>
```

But when i run this script, the directories are not created, and i have these errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log :

```
[Sat Dec 03 18:47:44.590884 2016] [:error] [pid 1295] [client 192.168.1.11:50940] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/pi/html/createDir.php on line 2
[Sat Dec 03 18:47:44.591949 2016] [:error] [pid 1295] [client 192.168.1.11:50940] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/pi/html/createDir.php on line 3
```

Here are the permissions for the directory /mnt/hdd :

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  32K Jan  1  1970 hdd
```

My apache server is using default configuration (www-data user and group). There is a permission issue on the folder /mnt/hdd but i can't figure it out, can someone give me a clue ?

Comment: You will need to give write permissions to the folder (sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/hdd) but it will also allow security risks. Or Change the group and owner of the file sudo chown www-data:www-data /mnt/hdd. But then again, there should be a better, more secure way

Comment: But do i have to issue this command before mounting the device or after ?

Comment: After. And you need to use sudo. Sudo chown...

Comment: After mounting i'm getting an error :
sudo chown www-data:www-data /mnt/hdd
chown: changing ownership of ‘/mnt/hdd’: Operation not permitted

Comment: Another option is to use context http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878647/allow-apache-php-a-read-write-access-to-a-mounted-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems seems to comes whem i'm mounting the device. it's works when i mount the drive with the following command :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/hdd umask=000
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache is running in www-data group as you said, and hdd folder belongs to root, so Apache cant make directories because of privileges.Try

1. Make sure all files are owned by the Apache group and user.

   ```
   chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/webserver/www
   ```
2. Next enabled all members of the www-data group to read and write files

   ```
   chmod -R g+rw /path/to/webserver/www
   ```

Comment: i already tested the command chown www-data /mnt/hdd and it's not working. I'm concerned by th security of running apache under root

Comment: it's works but i didn't understand why. My www directory is in /home/pi/www, why permission on this folder affect the writing on /mnt/hdd ?

Comment: you added /mnt/hdd to web-data group and by second step you allowed  scripts in www folder write and read files which belongs to same group

Comment: it's not working.. when i mount the device the folder are not created.