# PHP cannot access mounted drive in Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Running Ubuntu 18.04, Apache/2.4.29, PHP 7.2.10.

I am unable to read/write into my mounted drives from PHP.

this is my sample code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$folder = '/media/superuser/HDD4TB_CRYPT/nextcloud_data';

var_dump(ini_get('open_basedir'));
file_put_contents($folder.'/x.txt', "AA");
echo file_get_contents($folder."/x.txt");

phpinfo();
```

This is output:

> string(0) ""
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/media/superuser/HDD4TB_CRYPT/nextcloud_data/x.txt):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/nextcloud/x.php on line 9
>
> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(/media/superuser/HDD4TB_CRYPT/nextcloud_data/x.txt):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/nextcloud/x.php on line 10

these are folder details:

```
superuser@SuperTower:/var/www/html/nextcloud$ ls -al /media/superuser/HDD4TB_CRYPT/
total 28
drwx------  4 superuser superuser  4096 feb  3 20:55 .
drwxr-x---+ 4 root      root       4096 feb  2 00:06 ..
drwx------  2 root      root      16384 feb  1 22:49 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data  www-data   4096 feb  3 21:29 nextcloud_data
```

I tried editing open_basedir, but this did not help to solve any issues, so I just commented it out. Therefore `open_basedir` has `no value` in `phpinfo()`. Folder is chowned to www-data (this is apache user) and also chmoded to 777.

`/media/superuser/` contains folders with mounted drives on my PC. `superuser` is my username in Ubuntu.

Thanks for any ideas!

P.S.

I have also tried adding a symlink to my folder:

```
superuser@SuperTower:/var/www/html/nextcloud$ ls -al data
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 45 feb  3 21:05 data -> /media/superuser/HDD4TB_CRYPT/nextcloud_data/
```

and using

```
$folder = '/var/www/html/nextcloud/data';
```

but the results are exactly the same.

I also tried adding

```
 <Directory /var/www/html/nextcloud/data>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Allow from All
 </Directory>
```

no change in the resulting behavior :/

Comment: check link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878647/allow-apache-php-a-read-write-access-to-a-mounted-directory hope help

Comment: yea, saw that but seems like a bad solution, I dont mount folders myself, /etc/fstab does that for me

Comment: You must ensure that the user *or* group of the webserver process (which runs PHP as a sub-process or module) has access permissions to the directory. In case of Apache this usually would be the user and group `www-data`. So first find out the user and group of your webserver and then ensure the directory permissions of the share are correct.

Comment: as you can see from my outputs of ls - al in question www-data owns the folder i want to write into

Comment: What about the permissions of the `x.txt` file?

Comment: there is no x.txt file, i want to be able to create ane new files/folders in that folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason no matter what ownership/permissions I set on folder, /media/superuser is never accessible by www-data.

I edited /etc/fstab to mount drive into /opt/ folder and I chowned it to www-data user and group.

Works like a charm now.